# Example algorithm time complexity

Tags: time, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I have recently understand the Big Oh notation. I have recently came across the example given in the book.

```
void Function(int n)
{
int i=1 ;
int s=1 ;
while( s <= n)
{
i++ ;
s= s+i ;
print(\*");
}
}
```

I don't know how does the author arrives at the time complexity of the above algorithm as O(√n). I just want to understand the process for arriving at this conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can easily be seen as `s is growing quadratic in terms of number of iteration`.

`s = 1 // set as 1 initially`
Now we are adding `S = s + i // Where i increasing linearly by one unit in each iteration`

`//So it's just a addition i.e. s = 1 + 2 + 3 +4 ....+i,  which will sum up to s = i(i+1)/2`
Hence `s = i(i+1)/2 = (i^2+i)/2` where i is the number of iteration.

Now, In `i` iteration we are getting `s  = (i^2+i)/2`
To get `s >=n` we required only `√n` iterations.
Hence the time-complexity of given program will be `O(√n)`.

Comment: I don't understand how you identify that s=i(i+1)/2 ? is there any mathematics topics that needs to be read for this ? How does it become O(√n).Apology for asking too many questions but I am putting my all efforts to understand the time complexity analysis.

Comment: I have edited the answer, see if you can understand.

Comment: Thanks Shravan. I got that how do you ge that expression s=(i^2+i)/2.But  I dont' understand how does it become O(√n). Apology once again for eating your head.

Comment: But in case if we want to prove it mathematically To get s >=n we required only √n iterations. How do we prove it?

Comment: @Beast so s=(i^2+i)/2 and you want s=>n which is the same as (i^2+i)/2 >=n . Please note that i denotes the number of times that loop will be executed since you increase it by 1 each time. The (i^2+i)/2 >=n inequality is quadratic and (for simplicity) you can reduce it to i^2>=n => i>=√n.

Comment: Thanks Shravan and  tchrikch. One last question would be any specific maths topics I need to go through to understand and resolve the problems of time complexity.

Comment: I would say no, if you understand the basic concept of mathematics like A.p, G.P, recursion, Logrithm and polynomial functions. You can see this book http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall07/cos433/mathcs.pdf if you really want something.